# First call of query on big table is surprisingly slow

Tags: postgresql, configuration, query-optimization, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-performance

I have a query that feels like it is taking more time then it should be. This only applies on the first query for a given set of parameters, so when cached there is no issue.

I am not sure what to expect, however, given the setup and settings I was hoping someone could shed some light on a few questions and give some insight into what can be done to speed up the query. The table in question is fairly large and Postgres estimates around 155963000 in it (14 GB).

#### Query

```
    select ts, sum(amp) as total_amp, sum(230 * factor) as wh
    from data_cbm_aggregation_15_min
    where virtual_id in (1818) and ts between '2015-02-01 00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59'
    and deleted is null
    group by ts
    order by ts
```

When I started looking into this the query it took around 15 seconds, after some changes I have gotten it to around 10 seconds which still seems long for a simply query like this. Here are the results from `explain analyze`:  http://explain.depesz.com/s/97V1. Note the reason why `GroupAggregate` returns the same amount of rows is this example only has one `virtual_id` being used, but there can be more.

#### Table and index

Table being queried, it has values inserted into it every 15 minutes

```
CREATE TABLE data_cbm_aggregation_15_min (
  virtual_id integer NOT NULL,
  ts timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  amp real,
  recs smallint,
  min_amp real,
  max_amp real,
  deleted boolean,
  factor real DEFAULT 0.25,
  min_amp_ts timestamp without time zone,
  max_amp_ts timestamp without time zone
)

ALTER TABLE data_cbm_aggregation_15_min ALTER COLUMN virtual_id SET STATISTICS 1000;
ALTER TABLE data_cbm_aggregation_15_min ALTER COLUMN ts SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

The index that is used in the query

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_data_cbm_aggregation_15_min_virtual_id_ts
ON data_cbm_aggregation_15_min USING btree (virtual_id, ts DESC);

ALTER TABLE data_cbm_aggregation_15_min
CLUSTER ON idx_data_cbm_aggregation_15_min_virtual_id_ts;
```

#### Postgres settings

Other settings are default.

```
default_statistics_target = 100 
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB 
effective_cache_size = 11GB
work_mem = 256MB
shared_buffers = 3840MB
random_page_cost = 1
```

#### What I have tried

I have been following the Things to try before you post in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and the results in a bit more detail were as follows:

1. Fiddling with the Postgres settings, mostly lowering `random_page_cost` since the index scan, while it seems not too special is miles ahead of the bitmap heap scan it tried doing instead when the `random_page_cost` was higher.
2. Adding increased statistics to the `virtual_id` and `ts` columns which the index and `WHERE` conditions are based on. The query planner's estimated row count was much closer to the actual row count after changing this.
3. Clustering on `the idx_data_cbm_aggregation_15_min_virtual_id_ts` index did not seem to change much, not that I noticed.
4. Running `VACUUM` manually did not change much, I am already running autovacuum so this was no surprise.
5. Running `REINDEX` on the index shrunk it considerably (by almost 50%!) but it did not improve the speed by much.

Comment: How is the data distributed? ie, how many distinct values of `virtual_id` are there, and do they have roughly the same number of rows? Do you typically query by whole months, or can the time ranges be arbitrary?

Comment: As of now there are 15256 distinct `virtual_id` values in the table. The total amount of rows associated with each `virtual_id` varies but all of them get data at the same rate, so the variation is based on when they were created. The query in question will have arbitrary time ranges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### A **couple of small improvements**

```
SELECT ts, sum(amp) AS total_amp, sum(factor) * 230  AS wh
FROM   data_cbm_aggregation_15_min
WHERE  virtual_id = 1818
AND    ts >= '2015-02-01 00:00'
AND    ts <  '2015-04-01 00:00'
AND    deleted IS NULL
GROUP  BY ts
ORDER  BY ts;
```

- <strike>`sum(230 * factor)`</strike> - it's cheaper to multiply the sum *once* instead of multiplying each element: `sum(factor) * 230` The result is the same, even with NULL values.
- <strike>`ts between '2015-02-01 00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59'`</strike> is potentially *incorrect*. To include *all* of March 2015, use the presented alternative. `BETWEEN` is translated to `ts >= lower AND ts <= upper` anyway. It is *always* slightly faster to spell it out.
- <strike>`virtual_id in (1818)`</strike> is just a needlessly convoluted way to say `virtual_id = 1818`.

#### Better index, potentially **bigger improvement**

```
CREATE INDEX data_cbm_aggregation_15_min_special_idx
ON data_cbm_aggregation_15_min (virtual_id, ts, amp, factor)
WHERE deleted IS NULL;
```

- I see nothing in your question that would suggest `DESC` in your original index. While `Index Scan Backward` is almost as fast as a plain `Index Scan`, it's still better to drop the modifier.
- Most importantly, there are [**index-only scans**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) since Postgres 9.2. The two index columns I appended (`amp`, `factor`) only make sense if you get index-only scans out of it.
- Since you obviously are not interested in deleted rows, make it a partial index. Only pays if you have more than a few deleted rows in the table.
  If you have other large parts of the table that can be excluded, add more conditions - and remember to repeat the condition in the query (even if it seems redundant) so Postgres understands that the index is applicable.

#### Table definition

Reordering table columns like this would save 8 bytes per row:

```
CREATE TABLE data_cbm_aggregation_15_min (
   virtual_id integer NOT NULL,
   recs smallint,
   deleted boolean,
   ts timestamp NOT NULL,
   amp real,
   min_amp real,
   max_amp real,
   factor real DEFAULT 0.25,
   min_amp_ts timestamp,
   max_amp_ts timestamp
);
```

Related:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43142/3684)

#### Most important information for last

- The first query call can be substantially more expensive for very big tables, since the whole table cannot be cached. Subsequent calls profit from the populated cache. Postgres caches blocks, not necessarily whole tables.
- One more thing that can be important for the *first* call. Due to the MVCC model of Postgres it has to maintain visibility information. When reading pages of a table the first time since the last write operation, Postgres opportunistically updates visibility information, which can impose some extra cost for the first access (and help a lot for subsequent calls). [More in the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND). Related answer on dba.SE:

  - [Why does a SELECT statement dirty cache buffers in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81187/3684)

#### About what you've tried so far

- `SET STATISTICS 1000` for `ts` and `virtual_id` was an excellent idea, but the effect was largely nullified by setting `random_page_cost = 1`, which basically forces an index scan for this query either way.
- `random_page_cost = 1` is telling Postgres that random access is just as cheap as sequential access. This makes sense for a DB that (almost) completely resides in cache. For a DB with huge tables like yours, this setting seems **too extreme** (even if it gets Postgres to favor the desired index scan). Set it to `random_page_cost = 1.1` or probably higher.
- A bitmap index scan is typically a *good* plan for the first call of the query you presented - for data distributed randomly across the table. Since you clustered the table just like you need it for this query, an index scan is more efficient. The question is: will your table *stay* clustered?
- Your settings for [**`work_mem`**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server#work_mem) and other resources depend on how much RAM you have, the speed of your disks, on access pattern, how many concurrent connections you typically have, what other programs on the server compete for resources, etc. **`work_mem = 256MB` seems *too high***. You don't need nearly as much for the presented query. Setting it that high may actually *harm* performance, because it reduces RAM available to cache.
- `REINDEX` is not redundant immediately after `CLUSTER`, since that recreates all indexes anyway. You must have run `REINDEX` *before* cluster, or you have heavy write access on the table to get so much bloat again already.

#### Various

- Upgrade to Postgres 9.4 (or the upcoming 9.5, currently alpha). Version 9.2 is 3 years old now, the latest version has received many improvements.
- The [query plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/97V1) suggests that ***nothing* is actually aggregated**. `rows=4,117` are read from the index and `rows=4,117` remain after `GroupAggregate`. Looks like rows are unique on `ts` already? Then you can remove the aggregation completely and make it a simple `SELECT` ...
- If that's just a misleading `EXPLAIN` output and you typically output much fewer rows than are read, a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html) with index on `ts` would be another option. Especially in combination with Postgres 9.4, which introduces [`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html).

Comment: An amazing answer. But isn't it also a filesystem cache that makes the consequent queries faster?

Comment: @zerkms: Yes, file system cache and Postgres cache together.

Comment: These suggestions look very helpful, I will try them out and report back with the results, thanks a lot! 

The use of `IN` operator on `virtual_id` is there since there can be more than one. But like you mentioned it might be worth when I have only one `virtual_id` like in the example to use `=` and skip `group by` since they do nothing in that specific case.